# How to fix size limit error when performing actions on hive table in pyspark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hbase

I have a hive table with 4 billion rows that I need to load into pyspark. When I try to do any actions such as counting against that table, I get the following exception (followed by `TaskKilled` exceptions):

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o89.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6732 in stage 13.0 failed
4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6732.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 30759, some_server.XX.net, executor 38): org.apache.hive.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol mess
age was too large.  May be malicious.  Use CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit() to increase the size limi
t.
```

My version of HBase is 1.1.2.2.6.1.0-129 and I am unable to upgrade at this time.

Is there some way I can get around this issue without upgrading, maybe by modifying an environment variable or config somewhere, or by passing an argument to pyspark via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I would say no.

Based on the following JIRAs increasing the protobuf size seems to require a code change since all these JIRAs were resolved with code patches using `CodedInputStream` as suggested by the exception.

- [HDFS-6102](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6102) Lower the default maximum items per directory to fix PB fsimage loading
- [HDFS-10312](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-10312) Large block reports may fail to decode at NameNode due to 64 MB protobuf maximum length restriction.
- [HBASE-14076](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14076) ResultSerialization and MutationSerialization can throw InvalidProtocolBufferException when serializing a cell larger than 64MB
- [HIVE-11592](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11592) ORC metadata section can sometimes exceed protobuf message size limit
- [SPARK-19109](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19109) ORC metadata section can sometimes exceed protobuf message size limit